# Define Cross Schema foreign key in Prisma

Tags: postgresql, express, foreign-keys, prisma

I have a schema file in my admin folder that has a plans model defined as follows:

*//Admin/schema.prisma*

```
model plans {
    id          String     @id @default(uuid())
    name        String     @unique
    bookmark    String?
    color       String?
    orderNumber Int?
    price       Float      @default(0)
    aPrice      Float      @default(0)
    discount1M  Float      @default(0)
    discount1Y  Float      @default(0)
    hidden      Boolean    @default(false)
    description String?
    permissions String[]
    limits      Int[]
    createdAt   DateTime   @default(now())
    updatedAt   DateTime   @updatedAt
    payments    payments[]
}
```

I also have a schema file in my tenants folder which has a model called tenant that needs to have a plan ID. I tried to define it as follows:

*//Tenants/schema.prisma*

```
model tenant {
    id         String   @id @default(uuid())
    name       String
    expiry     DateTime @db.Date
    status     Boolean
    sentEmails Int
    planId     String
    plan       plans    @relation("plans", fields: [planId], references: [id])
references: [planId])
}
```

But I am getting this error:
Type "plans" is neither a built-in type, nor refers to another model, custom type, or enum.
How can I do this relation? Is it even possible?